# What's the remote server url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

How do I know what my URL is when the server is not local?
have now uploaded the server through HEROKU.

Here are the errors and code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: just dont hardcode `http://localhost:3000` in your code.. a form action will work without it.

Comment: You will probably want to use DNS so you can connect a domain name to your server's IP address and then create URLs with your domain name in them.  I don't know Heroku well enough to know if they offer this service for you or if you have to go elsewhere to get it.

Answer (score 1):

It tells you in the settings page for the app on the Heroku dashboard under "Domains".

[image: screenshot of Heroku dashboard]